# What does it mean when we say the estimators need to be independent when using Ensemble Methods in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, model, independence, ensemble-learning, methodology

In collective learning (ensemble methods) we need the estimators to be Independent/ uncorrelated from one another. Do I understand correctly, that this means we need to draw the data samples without replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the independence of estimators does not come from the sampling technique.

Empirically, ensembles tend to achieve better performance when there is more diversity between models. To achieve this diversity (*not to be confused with independence*), randomized training sets can be generated (with or without replacement). Models are then trained on different samples (see e.g. Bootstrap Sampling/Bagging) and then combined e.g. by averaging. Parallel training is possible because your estimators are independent.

In contrast, boosting is an example of an ensemble method based on sequential training where each estimator tries to correct the mistakes of the previous basic learner. By definition, learners are not independent.

Comment: Ah I see ! So when we say the estimators are independent, it means they do not learn iteratively ("through past experience"). A model that does not learn through iterations would be bagging. But if we have a model that learns sequentially, like Boosting we have dependent estimators?

Comment: first of all it means that training one estimator does not affect the training process of another. "through past experience" does not matter here.

Comment: Yes to the bagging part. Training Boosting algorithms cannot be parallelized, because estimators are dependent, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for helping me clarify!